# Woocommerce: get total number of items in order

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

This seems so simple, but it was late and I might have been over-complicating things!

I'm currently using the `woocommerce_thankyou` hook in the `WP` functions file to compile some data and send it to a third party API. So far, so easy, using standard `$order` and `$order_meta values`.  But I need to get the total number of items in an order, and I can't see where to get it.

So if someone orders `2` green widgets and `3` blue widgets, I need to get `5` from somewhere.

Am I missing something obvious? :-)

Comment: `$order = new WC_Order( 1 );
$order_items = $order->get_items(); echo count($order_items);`

Comment: Thanks Gulshan. I tried something similar and it gives '2'; as in green widgets and blue widgets, in the above example.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Counting order items can be 2 different things:

1. Total items count:

   // Get an instance of the WC_Order Object
   $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

   $items_count = count( $order->get_items() );

   // Testing output
   echo $items_count;
2. The total items quantity count:

   // Get an instance of the WC_Order Object
   $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

   $total_quantity = 0; // Initializing

   // Loop through order items
   foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
   $total_quantity += $item->get_quantity();
   }

   // Testing output
   echo $total_quantity;

Or you can use the WC_Order `get_item_count()` method that do the same *(see [**its source code**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Order.html#1808-1831))*:

```
// Get an instance of the WC_Order Object
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

$total_quantity = $order->get_item_count();
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this to get total items in a order -

```
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
echo $order->get_item_count(); // Will display the total numbers
```

Comment: Thanks for this - looking at the woo docs, it says this function "Gets the count of order items of a certain type" - does that mean if the cart has a mix of simple and variable products then it will fail?

Comment: Yes it will works for mix types of order items as well.